# Mockito with delete method which emits entity entity object in spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-webflux

I am trying to run junit using mockito with Spring webflux. Here delete method returns Mono data and emits entity object using thenReturn as per below code. The issue here is when I am trying to mock this object, it takes Mono only and giving null pointer at next line.  I am getting null pointer as shown in actual code. How can i return entity object in mockito for delete repository method.
Actual code

```
    Mono<SuccessResponse> method1(RequestDto dto){
    return repo.findById(dto.getId())
    .flatMap(m -> {
         Mono<ABC> ref= repo.delete(m).thenReturn(m);
         return ref.flatMap(f -> {
         if (f.getId() != 0) // Null pointer 
         return Mono.just(new SuccessResponse());
         }
    }
 }
```

Junit Test - i tried with mocks but none of them is working.

```
    //Mockito.when(repo.delete(CommonUtil.ABC())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
    //Mockito.doReturn(Mono.just(CommonUtil.ABC())).when(repo).delete(service.method1());
    //Mockito.when(CommonUtil.ABC().getId()).thenReturn(7L);
```

Comment: Can you please include the complete code? What is `m`? Thanks

Comment: @JoãoDias - added code. m is the response of DB which creates entity object to delete. If DB record not found then no need to call repo.delete() method .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to "tell" your mock to return the object provided to `delete()` as follows:

```java
Mockito.when(repo.delete(any())).then(returnsFirstArg());
```